# Not finding file on foreign operating system

Tags: vb.net, operating-system

I'm now in charge of managing a program at work that, when launched, checks the directory the program is located in for a license file.  This code has always worked perfectly fine, but when we installed the program on a client's computer who uses a foreign OS (Japanese Windows to be exact), the program cannot find the file.

Here's the segment of code that's relevant:

```
Dim sr As StreamReader
Dim strLicenseFile As String

'---Here's where the path for the file is set.---
'---Both lines below have been tried, and still fail.---

strLicenseFile = Application.StartupPath & "\license.yvl"
strLicenseFile = "license.yvl"

If File.Exists(strLicenseFile) Then

   '---Here's where the majority of code is executed---

Else

   '---And here's where the program always goes, because the file isn't found---

End If
```

Why can't the file be found on a foreign OS?  I assume it has something to do with the character-set and path.

Comment: A couple things - (1) The startup path isn't necessarily the directory the program is located in. You can use [Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx) for that. (2) Instead of directly concatenating a directory name to a file name, use [IO.Path.Combine(folder, "license.yvl")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx).

Comment: True, when I'm using "Application.StartupPath & "\license.yvl" that might be an issue, but how about when I'm just setting strLicenseFile to "license.yvl"?  Wouldn't that always be using the same path as the program?

Comment: It depends on how the application is launched - I'd use the [.Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx) property just to make sure.